# setFrom alternative goDaddy

Tags: phpmailer

I understand that gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc. etc. won't work with goDaddy and PHPMailer but what email address should I use for setFrom? I would appreciate any help in figuring this out! (I'm trying to have the name and email entered on an html contact form be emailed to me)

```
<?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  require 'Exception.php';
  require 'PHPMailer.php';
  require 'SMTP.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->isSMTP();
  
  $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
  
  $mail->Host = 'localhost';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
  $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
  $mail->Port = 25;

  //Set who the message is to be sent from
  $mail->setFrom('MY_UNUSABLE_EMAIL', 'MY_NAME');

  //Set an alternative reply-to address
  $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

  //Set who the message is to be sent to
  $mail->addAddress('MY_UNUSABLE_EMAIL', 'MY_NAME');
  
  // Content
  $mail->Body = <<<EOT
  You've recieved a new submission from: {$_POST['name']}.
  Their email is: {$_POST['email']}.
EOT;

  $mail->Send();
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you refer to GoDaddy’s docs on this. I expect they will want you to use an address that’s either associated with your account, or in a domain handled by their mail servers. Generally speaking, you’re not going to have a great deal of success either way; GoDaddy is a bit of a disaster as far as email goes.

Comment: I tried using a cpanel domain email but I'm not having any success. Maybe their Office 365 might work but that extremely cost prohibitive.

Comment: Ask GoDaddy support - it’s what you’re paying them for.